# Pyramid Pattern in Java with Star followed by a underscore

Tags: java

I want to print the following pattern:

> ```
> *
> *_*
> *_*_*
> *_*_*_*
> *_*_*_*_*
> ```

But the issue here is I am unable to eliminate last `_` symbol, this is the output that I am getting:

> ```
> *
> *_*_
> *_*_*_
> *_*_*_*_
> *_*_*_*_*_
> ```

```
int row =5;
String star="*";
String undrscr="_";
String s;
for(int i=1;i<=row;i++)
{//System.out.print(undrscr);
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {           
        if(i==1)
        {
        System.out.print(star);
        }
        if(i>1)
        {
            System.out.print(star+""+undrscr);
        if(j==i)
        {
            System.out.print("");
        }
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your inner for-loop to:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            System.out.print(star);
        }
        if (i > 1) {
            System.out.print(star);
            if (i - 1 >= j) {              // <-- change made in this if-block only
                System.out.print(undrscr);
            }
            if (j == i) {
                System.out.print("");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Before printing *underscore* check whether `i - 1 >= j` because as per your requirement the number of *underscores* is always 1 less than the number of *stars*.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the block `if(i>1){...}` to print `undrscr` only if `j!=i` like this :

```
                if(i>1)
            {
                // print only star
                System.out.print(star);
                // print undrscr if j!=i
                if(j!=i)
                {
                    System.out.print(undrscr);
                }
            }
```

And you will get the pattern :

```
*
*_*
*_*_*
*_*_*_*
*_*_*_*_*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//i was the rowNum and the number of stars of that row
for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum<=rows; rowNum++) {
    int numStars = 0;
        while (numStars<rowNum) {
            System.out.print(star+undrscr);
            numStars++;
        }
        System.out.println(star);
    }
```

Output:

```
*
*_*
*_*_*
*_*_*_*
*_*_*_*_*
*_*_*_*_*_*
```

EDIT: Better use this approach, you would get 5 rows instead of 6.

```
for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum<=rows; rowNum++) {
    int numStars = 1;
    while (numStars<rowNum) {
        System.out.print(star+undrscr);
        numStars++;
    }
    System.out.println(star);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    int row = 5;
    String star = "*";
    String undrscr = "_";
    String s;
    for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

            System.out.print(star);
            if (i != j)
                System.out.print(undrscr);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this stars are in increasing order of rows (i.e. 1 star in first row, followed by 2 stars in second and so on).

Step by step descriptive logic to print **right triangle star with underscore** pattern.

1)Input number of rows to print from user. we pass 5 Rows.

2)To iterate through rows run an outer loop from 0 to 5 with loop structure for(i=0; i<=5; i++).

3)To iterate through columns run an inner loop from 0 to i with loop structure for(j=0; j<=i; j++). Inside the inner loop print star.

4)In column loop we check if i==j then print only star otherwise print star and underscore.

5)After printing all columns of a row, move to next line i.e. print new line.

```
 int i, j;
      for(i=0; i<5; i++)
      {
          for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
          {
             if(i==j)
             {
                 System.out.print("*");
             }
             else
             {
              System.out.print("*");
              System.out.print("_");
             }
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
```